# MySQL query select students who do not have all 'A' grade

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-administration

I have two tables, `gradereport` and `student`

The **gradereport** table has the **studentNo** which is a foreign key from the table **student** and it also has the grades for each student,

I must query the **gradereport** table to find out which students do not have all grade 'A' in the courses they took.

If they have any grades that are not 'A' then they should not be included in the results.

How can I query the table **gradereport** to find students who do not have all 'A's in their courses.

**gradereport table**

## [image: gradereport table]

**student table**

## [image: student table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Students who do not have all A grade could be found as

```
select s.*,
gr.section,
gr.grade 
from student s 
join gradereport gr on gr.studentNo = s.studentnumber 
group by s.studentnumber,gr.section 
having sum(gr.grade='A') <> count(*) ;
```

Or if you dont care about the `section` then

```
select s.* 
from student s 
join gradereport gr on gr.studentNo = s.studentnumber 
group by s.studentnumber 
having sum(gr.grade='A') <> count(*)
```

Comment: this works, what is the opposite of this to find student that has only all 'A' grades?

Comment: Simple just change the having clause as `having sum(gr.grade='A') = count(*)`

Comment: depending on the size of the table this query could take some time to compute since the having clause re-evaluates the query... you should just do an exclusion join

Answer (score 1):

you can do an exclusive check like so

```
SELECT distinct studentno FROM gradereport gr
WHERE gr.grade = "A"
AND NOT EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM gradereport
    WHERE grade <> "A"
    AND studentno = gr.studentno
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a9fb/3)

you could also do an exclusive join (my preference)

```
SELECT DISTINCT gr.studentno
FROM gradereport gr
LEFT JOIN gradereport gr1 ON gr1.studentno = gr.studentno AND gr1.grade <> "A"
WHERE gr1.studentno is null
```

[**BETTER DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a9fb/9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT student.name, student.number
FROM student, gradereport
WHERE student.number = gradereport.StudentNumber
AND gradereport.Grade != 'A'
```

Comment: This did not work, it returned 'Bob brown'  -- this student has all 'A' in his grades on the gradereport table, his studentNo is 8.

Comment: it works, is there any way to change the query to get the student that has ALL 'A' grades, which is 'bob brown'?

Answer (score 0):

Find all students which have at least one grade A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `StudentNo` FROM `gradereport` WHERE `Grade` = 'A'
```

Finding the oposite results:

```
SELECT `StudentNo` FROM `gradereport` WHERE `StudentNo` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `StudentNo` FROM `gradereport` WHERE `Grade` = 'A')
```

Comment: First query works, second query is giving me error in the subquery

Comment: This is just students that got at least 1 'A', not all 'A's.

Comment: Fixed the second query which should show all students which "do not have all 'A's in their courses" like you wrote in your question. @lase the second query is the main query the first is only to explain how i got the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

`SELECT 
     DISTINCT StudentNo 
 FROM
     gradereport GR
 WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM gradereport GR2 
         WHERE 
              GR.StudentNo = GR2.StudentNo 
              AND
              GR2.Grade != 'A'
      )`

Comment: that is identical to mine